# Array lines too thin in newtxmath

Tags: brackets, newtxmath

When using `newtxmath` the shorter horizontal lines on the top left
and top right of the square brackets surrounding an array are
sometimes too thin.  Compare them in the first and second arrays
in the example.  If you comment out `\usepackage{newtxmath}` the
line are both of the same thickness. I am using TeXLive 2022 on Windows.  The prob;em is visible in Acrobat, SumatraPDF and in orint.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$$
   H_4 = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr} 
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
      1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 
      1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 
      1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{array}\right], \qquad
   \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
             1 & 1\cr 1 & -1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

\end{document}
```

[image: Screendump]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Sure, it is not an viewer issue? Can you please add an screenshot of your result to your question?

Comment: Interestingly, if you swap out newtxtext and newtxmath for the older txfonts package, then both are thin. If you need a TImes clone, you might consider mathptmx or stix.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too much like work to consider.  But here, I introduce `\left\llbrac...\right\rrbrac` for a large extensible bracket.  However, this seems to have a minimum size limit and so I also introduce `\left\lbrac...\right\rbrak` to handle the small to intermediate size brackets.  They grab their forms from the `ptmx` font files.

I import them atop the loaded `newtxmath` package, so that everything else should remain in the new-tx font.  In the MWE below, I first show results in the native newtxmath brackets, and then I show the results with l(l)brac and r(r)brac.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{PTlargesymbols}{OMX}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{PToperators}{OT1}{ztmcm}{m}{n}


\DeclareMathDelimiter{\llbrak}{\mathopen}%
  {PTlargesymbols}{50}%
  {PTlargesymbols}{52}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrbrak}{\mathclose}%
  {PTlargesymbols}{51}%
  {PTlargesymbols}{53}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrak}
   {\mathopen}{PToperators}{91}{PTlargesymbols}{20}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrak}
   {\mathclose}{PToperators}{93}{PTlargesymbols}{21}

\begin{document}
\[
   H_4 = \left[\begin{array}{r}
       1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}\right]
      ,\qquad \left[\begin{array}{rrrr} 
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
      1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 
      1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 
      1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{array}\right], \qquad
   \left[\begin{array}{rr} 
             1 & 1\cr 1 & -1
  \end{array}\right], \qquad 
  \Biggl[\Bigl[ [1] \Bigr]\Biggr]
\]
\[
   H_4 = \left[\begin{array}{r}
       1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}\right]
      ,\qquad \left\llbrak\begin{array}{rrrr} 
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
      1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\ 
      1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\ 
      1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \end{array}\right\rrbrak, \qquad
   \left\lbrak\begin{array}{rr} 
             1 & 1\cr 1 & -1
  \end{array}\right\rbrak, \qquad 
  \Biggl\lbrak\Bigl\lbrak \lbrak1\rbrak \Bigr\rbrak\Biggr\rbrak
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem - many thanks.